# querying a list - returns only one value

Tags: linq, list

I have created a structure and list.

```
  public struct CarMake
{
    public string name;
    public string id;

}
```

I added structure objects to this (carMakers) and am trying to query

```
     string  selCar = from c in carMakers
                 where c.name == selectedCarMfgName
                 select c.id;
```

I am getting an error near select statement- cannont implicity convert IEnumerable to string. I know that query returns only one value, that's why I have like that.

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        carMakers.Add(new CarMake() { name = "Audi", id = "1234" });
        string selCar =(from c in carMakers
                        where c.name == "Audi"
                        select c.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Output- 1234

Answer (score 2):

```
  string  selCar = (from c in carMakers
                     where c.name == selectedCarMfgName
                     select c.id).SingleOrDefault();
```

Your query returns a collection (with one element). You should use `Single()` (or `SingleOrDefault()`) to get that one item. If the query can return more than one result, you should look into `First()` ( or `FirstOrDefault()`)

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the error message. It probably says something like

```
"cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable<string> to string."
```

The results of a query of a sequence is another sequence, an `IEnumerable<T>`. *You* may know that you expect only one result, but that's not what the query does. To obtain only one result, you can optionally include another extension method on the end.

```
yourQuery.First();
yourQuery.FirstOrDefault();
yourQuery.Single();
yourQuery.SingleOrDefault();
```

The difference in these is that the `First*` variations can work with sequenes with many elements, whereas the `Single*` variations will throw exceptions if more than one element is present. The `*OrDefault` variations support the concept of *no* matching elements, and returns the default value for the type (null in the case of classes, a default value (such as 0 for `int`) for structs).

Use the version that conforms to your expectation. If you expect one and *only* one match, prefer `Single`. If you only care about one out of arbitrarily many, prefer `First`.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor my query slightly:

```
var selCar = carMakers.Single(c => c.name == selectedCarMfgName).id;
```

This assumes you know that the car is in the list.  If not, use `SingleOrDefault` and check the return before getting the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done too much with LINQ but because you are selecting into a string you may need to use FirstOrDefault as your statement could return back more than one value yet your string can only hold one.

First will return null value I think if nothing is found but FirstOrDefault will return you a blank string.